# Add Row after Populating Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dialog

I have an HTML table and I want to be able to add a row after I click a button and a dialog box pops up where I can type in the necessary row information. I came across some code that does exactly what I want. I tailored it to go with my code as much as I could. So far, I have the popup box, but it does not add a row after I click "add row" in the popup which is what I need it to do. I was hoping someone might be able to tell me what is wrong with this. I'm pretty stuck on it.

HTML/PHP:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test1.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test1.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Vendor">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="mr_id">Vendor</label>
      <input type="text" name="mr_id" id="mr_id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="buyer_id">Buyer ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="buyer_id" id="buyer_id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_n">POC Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_n" id="poc_n" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_e" id="poc_e" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_p" id="poc_p" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>



<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
<table id="html_master" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header">
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Buyer ID</td>
    <td>POC Name</td>
    <td>POC Email</td>
    <td>POC Phone</td>
    <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
        <input type="button" class="deactivate" name="deactivate" value="Deactivate"></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>

</table>
</div>

        <input type="button" id="create-user" value="Add Row">

</body>  
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
// ----- Dialog Box -----

$( function() {
    var dialog, form,

      emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
      mr_name = $( "#mr_name" ),
      buyer_id = $( "#buyer_id" ),
      poc_n = $( "#poc_n" ),
      poc_e = $( "#poc_e" ),
      poc_p = $( "#poc_p" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( mr_name ).add( buyer_id ).add( poc_n ).add( poc_e ).add( poc_p ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
          min + " and " + max + "." );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function addVendor() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

      valid = valid && checkLength( mr_name, "mr_id", 3, 16 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( buyer_id, "buyer_id", 6, 80 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( poc_n, "poc_n", 5, 16 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( poc_e, "buyer_id", 6, 80 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( poc_p, "poc_n", 5, 16 );

      valid = valid && checkRegexp( mr_id, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, spaces and must begin with a letter." );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( buyer_id, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_n, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_e, emailRegex, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_p, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

      if ( valid ) {
        $( "#html_master tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + mr_name.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + buyer_id.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + poc_n.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + poc_e.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + poc_p.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" );
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
      }
      return valid;
    }

    var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Add Row": addVendor,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addVendor();
    });

    $( "#create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog( "open" );
    });
  } );
```

I know the validation is off right now, but that is not my current focus. I just want to be able to add a row after I populate the pop up window.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really tried to understand all of your code especially because there is an error in the JavaScript, but you should be able to use some JQuery here. Something along the lines of:

```
$("//Whatever your table's id/class is").append("<tr>//Whatever goes in here</tr>");
```

Does this help you? If not, please explain why if possible and I'll do what I can to give more effective feedback. Good luck, and good coding! :)

Comment: Not entirely sure what I would do with this code...so this would fix the problem of not being able to add a row after I populate the dialog box??

Comment: Yes, it should add a row. Emphasis on should... I don't know if you have a conditional statement that determines whether or not the "Add Row" button has been pressed.

Comment: So where would this go then? At the beginning? Inside addVendor function?